# Advantage of EJB transactions over spring transactions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

What exactly are the real benefits of EJB transaction management over Spring transaction management

Comment: They do the same thing, transaction management. Some people like JavaEE/EJB, some prefer Spring.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "EJB / Spring transaction management"? The transaction attributes you can use/define in both cases or the transaction managers functionality / performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the greatest advantages is that in Spring you need to configure transaction management by yourself, while in EJB you simply put annotations. More on EJB vs Spring transactions:

- [Java samples](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=812)
- [Java DZone](http://java.dzone.com/articles/transaction-management-ejb3-vs)

Comment: I do believe you can configure transaction attributes in Spring with annotations as well. The only additional (configuration) work is to define what transaction manager you want to use in Spring Framework.